# Audit every Ajax request in Oracle Database Table

Tags: jquery, ajax, oracle

Am trying to log orders being submitted to the database in a oracle DB I have created, But am unsure of how to go about it as am not very well versed in Ajax, and I do want to do this without the use of PHP.

Can anyone give me an idea, Point me in the right direction or offer an example?

My Ajax request At the moment:

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: xmlPostUrl,
                    data: {iXML: outputXML},
                    dataType: "xml",
                    contentType: "applicaton/xml",
                    success: function(result) {
                        alert(result);
                    },
                    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions){
    alert(xhr.status);
    alert(xhr.statusText);
    //alert(xhr.responseText);
                    }

               });
               console.log(outputXML);

                return false;
            });
```

Can anyone shed light on this for me :) Most things ave looked into required PHP which I do need want to use.

Comment: You have got to have something on the server-side to process the request....why not PHP?

Comment: Am already processing the request via a PL/SQL Controller am sending it too, and that works fine, I just need some of auditing/log in place.

Comment: If I understand you correctly then you should be able to add a logging function to the controller.

Comment: Thats a good starting Point really helps :) Any other ways to tackle it you could suggest?

Comment: Not really - any controller that you use, regardless of language, will have to have a logging function in order to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the advice ill look in to this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my PLSQL Package I am simply passing information to the local variables in my XML controller and calling a function in my Model to dynamically create the table in my front end application and also store the information in the back end.

Function to dynamically create front end table and store in back end table and only information only for a set user, in my own it will determine which use based on the cookie value in my Web Application:

```
        PROCEDURE gmi_audit_logs (i_ID             IN VARCHAR2,
                             i_USERNAME           IN VARCHAR2,
                             i_INSTANCE           IN VARCHAR2,
                             i_NAME               IN VARCHAR2,
                             i_OPERATION          IN VARCHAR2,
                             i_SUBMIT_DATE        IN DATE,
                             i_SENT_MODE          IN VARCHAR2,
                             i_RESULT             IN VARCHAR2)
   IS
   BEGIN
      INSERT INTO GUI_AUDITING_LOGS (ID,
                                         USERNAME,
                                         INSTANCE,
                                         NAME,
                                         OPERATION,
                                         SUBMIT_DATE,
                                         SENT,
                                         RESULT)
           VALUES (i_ID,
                   i_USERNAME,
                   i_INSTANCE,
                   i_NAME,
                   i_OPERATION,
                   i_SUBMIT_DATE,
                   i_SENT,
                   i_RESULT);


      COMMIT;
   END gmi_audit_logs;
```

I simply call this and pass information to the input parameters of that logging function based on the local variables values and input parameters where am calling it, this is how am calling it:

```
GUI_CAPABILITY_MODEL.gmi_audit_logs (id,
                                                   l_USERNAME,
                                                   l_INSTANCE,
                                                   l_NAME,
                                                   l_OPERATION,
                                                   i_post_date,
                                                   i_mode,
                                                   o_status);
```